# SQS to ECS (Fargate) or SQS to Lambda to ECS

Tags: aws-lambda, etl, amazon-ecs, amazon-sqs

This question is more of an architectural question about how best to build an ETL pipeline. At present, I have an AWS Lambda that is pinged via SQS. But processing data can take a little more than 15 minutes (runtime limit of AWS) and using the `sam build` for deployment results in a .zip larger than 250MB, therefore it throws an error. Therefore an alternative to AWS Lambda is needed. The alternatives what I'm seeing so far are:

SQS -> ECS (Fargate)
SQS -> Lambda -> ECS (Fargate)

I don't find any hints to the pro/cons of both options, and what is generally a preferred option. Any tips on how to approach this?

Comment: Just a tip - if your task is CPU bound, increasing lambda memory to 1.7GB will speed it up. Even if you don't need that much memory, anything less than that gives you a proportional fraction of a CPU. (And since it's proportionally faster, it will work out as about the same cost.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I don't find any hints to the pro/cons of both options, and what is generally a preferred option. Any tips on how to approach this?

As soon as you start running up against the 15 minute limits, or the deployment file size limits of Lambda, then it's probably time to move to ECS Fargate.

Please note that when you configured SQS as an event source for Lambda, behind the scenes AWS is actually running a process that polls the SQS queue for messages, and then calls your Lambda function with those messages. SQS never "pushes" messages anywhere, it is a "pull" service.

With that in mind, when moving to ECS you would need to change your code so that it polls SQS for messages to process. In general the way to configure this is to have a docker image that, when spawned as a container simply polls the SQS queue forever, processing any messages it receives. Then have ECS auto-scaling configured based on the number of messages in the SQS queue. When there are 0 messages in the queue, ECS can scale down to 0 running tasks. When there are messages in the queue, ECS can scale up to however many number of tasks you wish to run in order to process the messages. There's no need for Lambda in this setup.

Comment: thanks, great explanation. I infer that this SQS polling is achieved simply by boto3. What is unclear though is that the docker container contains the sqs polling code, and is "dormant" in the ECS, or have I misunderstood?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "dormant". You would create a docker image that contains the code. That image would be stored in an AWS ECR repository. ECS would create running containers from that image as needed. It could scale down to 0 running containers (to save cost) when there are 0 messages in the SQS queue.

Comment: Ok I think I see now. So when this message appears in the queue, then the containers start running and polls the said queue for the message, which is then parsed into the remainder of the app.

Comment: Yes exactly. You have two things monitoring the queue: 1. The ECS AutoScaling, which is just checking the `ApproximateNumberOfMessagesVisible` metric, to see if there are messages available for processing, for the purposes of scaling up or down the number of your running containers. 2. The SQS polling code inside the docker container(s) that pull the actual messages from the queue when the container(s) are running.